# k-th hitting time is a stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Could you check if my solution is correct? I find the filtrations quite tricky.

Here is the problem: Let $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a stochastic process and $B$ a borel set in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Prove that $ \tau_k = \inf \{n> \tau_{k-1}: \ X_n \in B\}$ is a stopping time w.r. to the natural filtration generated by the process.

Here is what I've done:

I assume that we know that the first hitting time is a stopping time and I want to prove the statement by induction.

Assume $\tau_k$ is a stopping time, $k \ge 1$.

We want to check if $\{ \tau_{k+1} \le n \} \in \mathcal{F}_n$ .

We have that $$\{ \tau_{k+1} \le n \} = \{ \tau_{k+1} =0 \} \cup \dots \cup \{ \tau_{k+1} =n \}  $$

$\{ \tau_{k+1} =0 \} = \emptyset$, because if $k \ge 1$ and $\tau_{k+1} =0$, then $\tau_{k} <0$.

Generally, $$\{ \tau_{k+1} =j \} = \{ \tau_{k+1} < j \} \cap \{X_{j} \in B\} \in \mathcal{F}_j$$

And using the inductive assumption for the first set, measurability and the fact that $\{X_n\}$ is adapted to the filtration with the property that $\forall n: \ \mathcal{F}_n \subset \mathcal{F}_{n+1}$, we get that $\{ \tau_{k+1} \le n \} \in \mathcal{F}_n$

Is everything correct here?

Comment: $$\{\tau_k\leqslant n\}=\bigcup_{I\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}^{|I|=k}\bigcap_{i\in I}\{X_i\in B\}$$

Comment: Thanks, Did. This equality makes everything look clearer. But my reasoning stays correct, right? :)

Comment: Well, it is not quite clear which induction you have in mind but anyway, the identity in your post stating that $\{ \tau_{k+1} =j \} = \{ \tau_{k+1} < j \} \cap \{X_{j} \in B\}$ is quite wrong. Maybe you have in mind to use $\{ \tau_{k+1} =j \} = \{ \tau_{k} < j \} \cap \{X_{j} \in B\}$ instead, but this is not true either.

Comment: @Did Yes, I had in mind that second equality. I wanted to prove that $\tau_n$ is a stopping time by induction on $k$.

Comment: Then $$\{\tau_{k+1}=j\}=\{X_j\in B\}\cap\bigcup_{i=k}^{j-1}\left(\{\tau_k=i\}\cap\bigcap_{n=i+1}^{j-1}\{X_n\notin B\}\right).$$