# Stopping time and Successive passage of barriers for a real Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

In a classic framework $(\Omega,\mathcal A, P)$ with $B=(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ a real Brownian motion and $(\mathcal F^B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ the canonical filtration tied to $B$.

Let this sequence of positives random variables $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ (with $T_0=0$) and the recursive relationship :
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb N,\ T_{n+1}=\inf\{t\geq T_n, \vert B_t-B_{T_n}\vert\geq 1\}
$$
I want to prove that $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of $(\mathcal F_t)$-stopping time.

*The correction simply written :*
$$
\{T_{n+1}\leq s\} = \{T_{n}\leq s\} \cap \{\underset{T_n\leq u\leq s}{\sup} \vert B_u-B_{T_n}\vert\geq 1\} \in\mathcal F_s (*)
$$

**But I do not understand why this intersection.**

My 2 observations about this problem :

1. I think that we can prove that : $\{T_{n+1}\leq s\} = \{\underset{T_n\leq u\leq s}{\sup} \vert B_u-B_{T_n}\vert\geq 1\} (**)$
2. $\{T_{n+1}\leq s\}\subseteq \{T_{n}\leq s\}$

(My observations are probably wrong, I do not know)

**Questions :**

If my observation (**) is true why the correction has written (*) ? 
(**) is not enough (to prove that it belongs to $\mathcal F_s$) ? Why it uses this intersection ? Is there a problem of open set ?

In the case that my observations are false, someone has understood (*) ?

Comment: A connected question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523989/k-th-hitting-time-is-a-stopping-time?rq=1

Comment: Well, basically the trouble is that it might be not clear what $$\sup_{x \in \emptyset} f(x)$$ means for some function $f$... and you can avoid this trouble by using the intersection.

Comment: what do you mean by $x\in\emptyset$ ?

Comment: Well, just take $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $T_n(\omega)>s$, then $$\sup_{T_n(\omega) \leq u \leq s} |B_u(\omega)-B_{T_n}(\omega)|$$ is exactly an expression of this form (because there is no $u$ such that $T_n(\omega) \leq u \leq s$). [And so, actually, the question is exactly the other way round: What do **you** mean by it...]

Comment: $\{T_{n+1}\leq s\} = \{\underset{T_n\leq u\leq s}{\sup} \vert B_u-B_{T_n}\vert\geq 1\}$ is false ?

Comment: Moreover, when we write $ \{\underset{T_n\leq u\leq s}{\sup} \vert B_u-B_{T_n}\vert\geq 1\}$, we suppose that the $\omega$s follow : $T_n(\omega)\leq u\leq s$, am I wrong ?

Comment: Why should we suppose this? You are leaving it to the reader to make sense of the things you are writing; it is much clearer to write proofs in such a way that the reader doesn't has to guess/suppose certain things. In this case, you can avoid all this by using the intersection - and it doesn't do you any harm, does it?